# How to fix audio.play() is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I can't see why it doesn't work.It seems all fine

```
const button = document.querySelector('.play');
const alarm = document.getElementById('alarm');



button.addEventListener('click',function(){
   alarm.play();
})
```

this is the html :

```
        <audio id="alarm">
            <source src="sound/Wecker-sound.mp3">
        </audio>
```

Comment: add `console.log(alarm)` in the event handler ... check it's what it should be

Comment: Your question says `audio.play()` is not a function, but in the code it is `alarm.play()`.

Comment: not an answer, but it always makes me sad to see someone make an anonymous function which does nothing other than call another (named) function. You can write this much more concisely, and just as (if not more) understandably, as `button.addEventListener("click", alarm.play);`

Comment: when i console log audio i get   the html i wrote earlier ..It really doesn't make sense i am following a tutorial and noone else seems to have this issue

Comment: `@Robin Zigmond`, maybe OP wants to put more code in there `onclick`, like change a CSS class or something. Also, it should be noted that only the `Event` Object is passed to the Event Listener, so if you wanted to pass multiple arguments *(or anything other that the Event Object)* to a function that technique is used all the time. Not sure why your comment was voted up.

Comment: Try to add `controls` attribute to your `audio`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a better answer. This is for when I search SO in a year: I got the 'audio.play() is not a function' error because I was accidentally creating a malformed  object that didn't have the right properties (stupidity with renaming props being passed in React*), so JS choked trying to process the command. As soon as I fixed that and provided the proper file source, error went away.

*Original array of audio files had this.state keys like 'url' and 'id', but when i iterated over the array, i did dumb crap like , but then when building the actual  based on that, I was still trying to use 'url' and 'id' instead of the newly renamed props 'clip' and 'clipId'. I'm rambling, but it took me way too long to get this stuff worked out, and figure out my errors (and near as I can tell, I can probably get rid of a layer of props passing... refactoring to follow once its all up and running).

Comment: It's 4 years later. I have no idea what I was talking about here. This might have been the last project I built in React before having to focus on C# for work and getting distracted by creating games in C# in Unity.